# How to create list of lists for repeating elements

Tags: python, slice

I have the following list `A` and would like to create the list of lists `B`. How can I detect the repeating elements and avoid the later repeats because there is a different element in between?

```
A = [1,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,6,6,6,6,3,3,4,4,4,4,5]

B = [[1],[3,3,3,3],[4,4,4],[6,6,6,6],[3,3],[4,4,4,4],[5]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) can do this for you.

```
>>> [list(x[1]) for x in itertools.groupby(A)]
[[1], [3, 3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4], [6, 6, 6, 6], [3, 3], [4, 4, 4, 4], [5]]
```

Comment: What if my A was like: `A = [(a,1),(b,3),(c,3),,(b,3),(a,3),(b,4),(c,4),(d,4),(e,6),(a,6),(c,6),(d,6),(a,3),(b,3),(c,4),(d,4),(c,4),(e,4),(a,5)]` where a,b,c,d,e are just irrelevant but I still would like to group based on 1,2,3... ? Is it possible to group by for a given index of tuple inputs?

Comment: You can use the ```key``` argument to ```groupby```, something like ```groupby(A, key=lambda v: v[1])```.